# Check octal number

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I write simple application in C++/Qt. And i have a text and some octal number in it. My app splits this text by spaces. And i need to check octal numbers from text. How can i select octal numbers from this text with regular expressions?

Thank you.

Comment: In what format is your text? What is the separator between your numbers? Can you post a few lines as an example?

Comment: example:

 x := 123; 

 a = 167;


All numbers are octal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex to match only octal numbers:

```
^0[1-7][0-7]*$
```

- `^,$`: Anchors
- `0`: A literal `0`. All octal numbers
  begin with a `0`.
- `[1-7]`: Char class for digits from 1
  to 7 as only these are valid octal
  digits.
- `*` : Quantifier for zero or more of the previous thing.

So basically this regex matches only those strings that have a `0` in the beginning and contain one or more digits from `1` to `7`.

If the leading `0` requirement is not there you can use the regex:

```
^[1-7][0-7]*$
```

Comment: or simplier ^0[0-7]+$
+: is quantifier for one or more times

But it will also catch 00 as valid octal number

Comment: @Vestnik: This allows numbers like `007`. I wanted to avoid `>1` leading zeros.

Comment: The question didn't mention avoiding more than one leading zero, and `007` is a perfectly valid octal number.